# Переименовать файлы в папке по условию

Tags: windows-10, bat

Есть множество файлов (в моём случае `.png`), почти у всех файлов название по-типу `1498246332_empire_1481`.
Файлы нужно переименовать так, чтобы осталось только последнее число, при этом учитывать наличии этого числа в конце, если он есть, то переименовать, если нет, то оставить как есть.

Как сделать это быстро, допустим на основе `.bat`?

---

Увы, попыток предоставить не могу, могу только написать что-то похожее на JS, как пример.

```js
let files = [
  '1498246332_empire_1481.png',
  '1498241232_cbipok_2513.png',
  '1498241662_none_number.png'
];

for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
  if(files[i].match(/_(\d+).png$/gm))
    files[i] = files[i].replace(/(.+)_(\d+)/gm, '$2');

console.info(files);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение через [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/) и функцию "Групповое переименование":

Выбираем нужные файлы, далее в меню выбираем раздел "Файлы" > "Групповое переименование" (или сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее в "Поиск и замена" выставляете нужные значение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Программа сразу покажет как будет выглядеть замена:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда всё будет готово нажмите "выполнить"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]